# How to pass date variable in JavaScript to XML?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a JavaScript application that takes values from a form in HTML and produces XML. As you can see below, I have a field in the form that has the ID Field 1, where the value is taken and assigned to variable Field1 that then gets fed into the template.

Now what I am after doing is creating a variable to store the creation time and feeding that into the template. How can I achieve this?

```
$(function () {
$('#DownloadButton').click(update);
});

var creationTime = new Date();

var template = [
'<Field1><?Field1?></Field1>',
'<creationtime><?creationTime?></creationTime>',

 ].join('\r\n');

function update() {
  var variables = {

'Field1': $('#Field1').val(),
};

 var newXml = template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/g,
function(match, name) {
  return variables[name];
    });
```